# Python highlighting in VSC

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting

My python code highlighting are not consistent in vsc lately, see the pictures. Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

[image: Highlighting doesn´t work]

And in another file the highlighting is right.

[image].

Any Ideas?

An idea where I probably have to change configurations.

Comment: are the files in the same workspace or different workspaces?  Does the .py file with "broken" formatting report any issues?  a missing " or ) or } would mess up all the formatting after it

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I´ve fixed it by changing the Python extension. I had selected "Python for VSCode", which is deprecated and no longer maintained. Changing it to the "Python" extension fixed my problem.